# Left join subquery gives invalid object name error

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, left-join

I have a SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 FROM [Mydb].[dbo].[Table1] AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT fk_id, Email FROM dbo.Table2 
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk_id
```

But this gives me the error:

```
Invalid object name 'dbo.Table2'.
```

Any idea why SQL Server does not recognize `Table2` in my subquery?

PS.

I tried to rename `dbo.Table2` to `[Mydb].[dbo].[Table2]`. But that gives me the same error.

Comment: Does is working as alone query? like.. `SELECT fk_id, Email FROM dbo.Table2`

Comment: Does `Table2` actually exist in `Mydb`? If it does, have you ensured that the schema is `dbo`?

Comment: @manurajhada Yes, when I select Table2 without the `LEFT JOIN` then it works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Your query formation isn't correct. no need of that subquery at all.

Your posted query

```
SELECT TOP 1000 FROM [Mydb].[dbo].[Table1] AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT fk_id, Email FROM dbo.Table2 
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk_id
```

Can be simplified as below, give it a try

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [Table1] t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if this is the problem but you have missed the asterisk (*) after top 1000. So maybe it should be something like the following

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM [Mydb].[dbo].[Table1] AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT fk_id, Email FROM dbo.Table2 
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.fk_id
```

If this doesnt work, remove `dbo` from `dbo.Table2` and then try.

Hope this helps.